# Borrar archivo utilizando script .txt

Tags: script

Quiero borra las información que tiene un Objeto Cuadrícula, que tiene como DATA SOURCE un archivo .TXT

No encuentro una función para lograr esto, estoy trabajando bajo el lenguaje script, Bajo la plataforma de programación InduSoft Web Studio .
Tenía pensado borrar el archivo .TXT y luego volverlo a crear, pero no me permite motivo a que Objeto Cuadrícula lo está utilizando.

[image: Objeto Cuadrícula utilizando]

El codigo que estoy utilizando al ejecutar no me muestra ningun tipo de error, solo el mensaje predestinado en el codigo ("file not deleted.." )
El codigo es este:

```
    $File_Delete=$FileDelete($GetAppPath() &"Data Historica LCB_USB.txt")
$wait (100)
Select Case $File_Delete
    Case 0
 MsgBox "file not deleted.."
    Case 1
 MsgBox "Success: file deleted."
  End Select

$wait (100) 
$File_Copy=$FileCopy ($GetAppPath() &"Data Historica LCB_USB - Copy.txt", $GetAppPath() &"Data Historica LCB_USB.txt",30)
Select Case $File_Copy
 Case -1 
 MsgBox "Timeout time expired. "
    Case 0
 MsgBox "Failed to copy file(s)."
    Case 1
 MsgBox "File(s) copied successfully."
  End Select
```

Alguna sugerencia. Gracias .

Comment: Hola. No está claro en qué lenguaje, framework o herramienta estás trabajando. Tampoco es claro cómo estás intentando solucionar tu problema ni en qué momento obtienes el error que indicas. Por favor, edita tu pregunta incluyendo esta información

Answer (score 0):

Resolví deshabilitando el  Grid Object, es decir cerrando la pantalla donde está el Grid Object ejecutando y usar  la función que me permite borrar.

```
    $File_Delete=$FileDelete($GetAppPath() &"Data Historica LCB_USB.txt")
$wait (100)
Select Case $File_Delete
    Case 0
 MsgBox "file not deleted.."
    Case 1
 MsgBox "Success: file deleted."
  End Select

$wait (100) 
$File_Copy=$FileCopy ($GetAppPath() &"Data Historica LCB_USB - Copy.txt", $GetAppPath() &"Data Historica LCB_USB.txt",30)
Select Case $File_Copy
 Case -1 
 MsgBox "Timeout time expired. "
    Case 0
 MsgBox "Failed to copy file(s)."
    Case 1
 MsgBox "File(s) copied successfully."
  End Select
```